# React Native - React Navigation - Go to app root (first route)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in a react native project and i am unable to find how to go back to navigation root (first screen in app) from an arbitrary screen. Navigation is like this:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {!loggedIn ? (
      // Login
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="LogInScreen" component={LogInScreen} /> 
      </Stack.Group>
    ) : (
      // App Screens
      <Stack.Group>
        // This Tab navigator may have more stacks inside
        <Stack.Screen name="AppTabsNavigator" component={AppTabsNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SomeErrorOutsideTabs" component={SomeErrorOutsideTabs} /> 
      </Stack.Group>
    )}
    // Error Modals
    <Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Screen name="SomeErrorScreen" component={SomeErrorScreen} /> 
    </Stack.Group>
  <Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContrainer>
```

Use cases are:

- User in `LogInScreen` causes some error -> `SomeErrorScreen` shows -> User press button to go back to `LogInScreen`.
- User in anywhere else causes some error -> `SomeErrorScreen` shows -> User press button to go back to first screen in `AppTabsNavigator` (sometimes does not work depending on inner stacks).

The summary is, no matter where you are, when you press button in `SomeErrorScreen` you must go back to "first app screen", which is `LogInScreen` if not logged in or first tab of `AppTabsNavigator` if logged in.

I have tried using `popToTop()` but it does not work when there are inners Stacks like `SomeResourceStack` inside `AppTabsNavigator` to contain index and show of resource, for example:

User in `AppTabsNavigator > SomeResourceStack > index` access to `AppTabsNavigator > SomeResourceStack > show`, cause `SomeErrorScreen` to appear and when going back, he goes back to `AppTabsNavigator > SomeResourceStack > show` instead of `AppTabsNavigator` first tab.

---

Answer:

The right answer is to use `reset` like Anthony Marino said and combine it with Ararat Ispiroglu suggestion. I controlled [Android's back button behavior](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/) as well:

```js
...

import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

...

const SomeErrorScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  ...

  const loggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.loggedIn)

  const onGoingBackButtonPress = React.useCallback(() => {
    navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ name: !loggedIn ? 'LogInScreen' : 'AppTabsNavigator' }]
    })
  }, [navigation, loggedIn])

  const androidBackButtonCallback = React.useCallback(() => {
    const onBackPress = () => {
      onGoingBackButtonPress()
      return true
    }

    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress)
    
    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress)
  }, [onGoingBackButtonPress])

  useFocusEffect(androidBackButtonCallback)

  ...

  return <View>
    <Button onPress={onGoingBackButtonPress } />
  </View>
}

export default SomeErrorScreen
```

Comment: You could use `navigation.navigate("LogInScreen")` if I understood you.

Comment: No, bacause the navigator used in SomeErrorScreen can navigate to LogInScreen only if you caused the error in LogInScreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset your navigator

```
navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [
              {
                name: 'SomeStackScreen',
                params: { someParam: 'Param1' },
              },
            ],
          })
```

As seen in the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to do that with your current navigation setup;

a) When you need to go back to root you can check if it's logged in or not

simply `navigation.navigate(loggedIn ? "AppTabsNavigator" : "LogInScreen")`

b) You can set the same name for the top level screen in the navigation for both logged and non-logged in screens. And navigation will pickup whichever screen is mouthed.

```
{!loggedIn ? (
      // Login
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="RootScreen" component={LogInScreen} /> 
      </Stack.Group>
    ) : (
      // App Screens
      <Stack.Group>
        // This Tab navigator may have more stacks inside
        <Stack.Screen name="RootScreen" component={AppTabsNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SomeErrorOutsideTabs" component={SomeErrorOutsideTabs} /> 
      </Stack.Group>
    )}
```

Comment: the first option is the way that you shouldnt take and wich documentation doesnt recommend.. the second option is the good option recommended by documentation